# Race conditions on Firebase DB / Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 classes that pull data from Firebase, display it using a List and then update the database. I'm worried I have a race condition in my structure.

I have MatchList class, the code is;

```
public class matchList extends ArrayAdapter<matches> {
private Activity context;
private List<matches> matchList;

public matchList(Activity context, List<matches> matcheslist) {
    super(context, R.layout.match_layout, matcheslist);
    this.context = context;
    this.matchList = matcheslist;
}
```

Which is being called from fragment_fixture class;

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Read from the database
    databaseMatches.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            matchesList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                matches match = matchSnapshot.getValue(matches.class);
                matchesList.add(match);
            }
            matchList adapter = new matchList (getActivity(), matchesList);
            listViewMatch.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

I finally have another fragment, refscorecard class;

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_refscorecard, container, false);

    //Home Score Button
    Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
    homeScoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
            String homeScore = (String) homeScoreBtn.getText();
            int homeScoreAdd = Integer.valueOf(homeScore.toString()) + 1;
            homeScoreBtn.setText(String.valueOf(homeScoreAdd));

            final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").child("Match_01");
            ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                @Override
                public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                    //return null;
                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    updates.put("homeScore", 3);
                    ref.updateChildren(updates);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }
            });
```

The problem I'm having is that when I change the value on the button click, the debug returns;

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

The lines it points too are (MatchList class);

```
super(context, R.layout.match_layout, matcheslist);
```

And this is being invoked from the fragment_fixture class;

```
matchList adapter = new matchList (getActivity(), matchesList);
```

I'm unsure of the call stack which maybe why I have this problem (what gets processed first, onStart, onCreateView, etc... and is this due to the speed of the database update where the corresponding read is reading too quickly before the data has been updated).

I have also tried putting the database update into a transaction block, but that doesn't resolve the problem.

This appears to be the Java events triggering quickly after the update (as the reads are listening for data changes) and its at a time whilst the DB is updating the field so it returns a null instead?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a Race Condition, this is more like a timing issue? Your `Fragment` call to `getActivity` returns null - what state is the hosting `Activity` at?

Comment: On all of the event listeners? Or just on the fixture fragment? For both, no I don't (guessing that's poor practice on my part, new to Android / Java, guessing I have to be a bit more proactive with flagging stuff ready for GC.)

Comment: Hi Mark, what state is the activity? Would you mind elaborating, I'm slightly lost :). It may not be a race condition on the DB part but on the all its self, as you mentioned timings in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment has been most probably destroyed when `ValueEventListener()` gives a callback.
You need to remove the `ValueEventListener()` in `onStop()`

```
// move to fragment class variables
ValueEventListener matchesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                matchesList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot matchSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    matches match = matchSnapshot.getValue(matches.class);
                    matchesList.add(match);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

 // in onStart()
databaseMatches.addValueEventListener(matchesListener);

// in onStop()
databaseMatches.removeEventListener(matchesListener);
```

Also you need to move

```
adapter = new matchList (getActivity(), matchesList);
listViewMatch.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to your `oncreate()`

Comment: I've made the changes, but how to I trigger the ValueEventListener matchesListener = new ValueEventListener() { as the databaseMatches.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {, if I run the changes in the onStart() it never gets triggered, so I'm presuming I have to call the matchesListener from inside onCreate?

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, the databaseMatches.removeEventListener(matchesListener); goes into the public void onStop() :)